# Command tutorial

Tags: magento2, command

I Magento to avoid commands completely on our first 2 website using Magento1, but it seems like I can't avoid it anymore with Magento2. Where do I start? I can find hundreds of tutorial online but i'm hoping to find a complete training relevant with Magento2. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is [with the official documentation from Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli.html). I personally like the work that Alan Storm did with this series of tutorials [about the object manager](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager/). Even though it's not focused on creating and using the new CLI, it's a great place to learn how to construct commands and how to read the code that does the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Magento U (https://u.magento.com/) offers official courses and certification; otherwise, the official starting point for documentation and tutorials is 
https://magento.com/resources/technical

Answer (score 1):

Best blog for command tutorial for magento. It may be useful to you. You can take reference from this blog :

http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/linux-useful-commands-list-488